# C language error: request for member ‘value’ in something not a structure or union

Tags: c

I got really confused why I can not use while loop to access the entire value for reading all of struct...Thank you guys... I think about 3 hours but have no clue. I do not know why does the value is not realized by the program, since I already defined that this is a struct.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct card{
    int isRed;
    int hasLetter;
    union{
        int charValue;
        int intValue;
    }value;
};

typedef struct card typeCard;
int deckValue(typeCard *deck[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    while(deck[i] != NULL){
        sum += deck[i].value.intValue;
        i += 1;
    }

    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int sum;

    typeCard card1 = {.isRed = 1,.hasLetter = 0,.value.intValue = 200};
    typeCard card2 = {.isRed = 100,.hasLetter = 0,.value.intValue = 200};
    typeCard deck[] = {card1,card2,NULL};

    sum = deckValue(deck);
    printf("%d",sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int deckValue(typeCard deck[])`

Comment: Also, declare the function before `main`

Comment: The problem needs to send the pointer, so it should be int deckValue(typeCard *deck[]), but I do not know if I want to keep it what should I do

Comment: Thx Antti! I will try to declare the function first, but is there a way I can leave the "*" sign?

Comment: It does pass a pointer.

Comment: int deckValue(typeCard *deck[]) so this should be right?

Comment: No. You've got 2 correct choices: `int deckValue(typeCard *deck)` or `int deckValue(typeCard deck[])` which are equivalent

Comment: Thank you so much!! but then I got a problem which another error happens, error: invalid operands to binary != (have ‘typeCard {aka struct card}’ and ‘void *’)

Comment: You cannot compare a `struct` with pointer. You need to either use a sentinel value (i.e., say last card has value -1 or something), or even better, pass the number of elements as another argument.

Comment: And also, deck is an array, and if I want to send it should I declared to be deck[], and also because I want to send the pointer though, I can add a * in the front, so it will be *deck[] or **deck?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the parameter to your function:

```
int deckValue(typeCard *deck[])
```

Doesn't match how you're using it:

```
sum += deck[i].value.intValue;
```

The function definition says that `desk` is an array of **pointers** to `typeCard`.  So when you do `deck[i].value` it thinks that you have an array of `typeCard`.

You instead want:

```
sum += deck[i]->value.intValue;
```

This will dereference the pointer for the array element.

Also in `main`, you're not passing an array of pointers to `typeCard`:

```
typeCard deck[] = {card1,card2,NULL};

sum = deckValue(deck);
```

You're passing an array of `typeCard`.  Since you want an array of pointers so you can use a NULL pointer as a sentinel, you need to change the definition to an array of pointers, and initialize the array elements accordingly:

```
typeCard *deck[] = {&card1, &card2, NULL};
```

Comment: Thank you!! I will try to understand it!

Comment: in this line: typeCard *deck[] = {&card1, &card2, NULL};

Comment: why do we need &?

Comment: `desk` is an array of pointers to `typeCard`, so you need to assign pointers to `typeCard` to the array elements.   The `&` operator takes the address of its operand.